# How to make pdf rendering non-editable or password protected

Tags: visualforce, security

I am trying to check the best possible secure solution.

Is it possible to make pdf rendering non-editable or password protected

Comment: Are you trying to stop people from rendering one? Or password protect it after it is generated? How are you generating it?

Comment: I am using renderedas pdf method for rendering. Is there any possibility to put password on preview so that unauthenticated people couldn't see that.  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean unauthenticated users? Why can't you use permissions of the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment below your question, you should be able to limit who can see your page by only adding specific profiles to the page.

1. From Setup, enter Visualforce Pages in the Quick Find box, then
   select Visualforce Pages.
2. Next to the name of the page that you want
   to restrict, click Security.
3. Select the profiles that you want to
   enable from the Available Profiles list and click Add.
4. Select the
   profiles that you want to disable from the Enabled Profiles list and
   click Remove.
5. Click Save.

From: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_security_page_def.htm&language=en_US